# datenum vs. datestr format in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I'm reading a string representing a date, yet it seem to ignore the input and use the default January as month, e.g.

```
>>datestr(now, 'YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS')

ans =

2011-11-02 19:04:09
```

but

```
>> datestr(datenum('2011-11-02 19:04:09', 'YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS'))

ans =

02-Jan-2011 19:04:09
```

What am I missing?

p.s. I use Windows 7 64 bit and Matlab R2011a, if it matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format your date is entered isn't supported by Matlab (see the datestr doc):

Use:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'
```

instead and it works fine...